# strapi start: "url is not defined" - using mlab mongo DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, mlab, strapi

When I run 'strapi start' I get the following output in my terminal:

> > debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
> >
> > > Error URL is not defined

Any solutions? I have recreated my mlab DB 3 times and when I enter all the values in the terminal to create the new strapi server I double check my values and everything from GitHub issues and strapi documentations say I'm doing the correct thing, but not able to figure out why this is happening! Appreciate any help!

Comment: Strapi needs Node v10 to be installed in order to work. If you upgrade your node version it should be working properly

Answer (score 4):

As @soupette have said in the comment:

> Strapi needs Node v10 to be installed in order to work. If you upgrade
>   your node version it should be working properly

I can confirm the same error on my end with NodeJS 8.11.1

Strapi's [GitHub page](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/README.md) confirms that minimum NodeJS version is 10.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok when you create a Mondo db on mlab you get this information:

```
 mongo ds129484.mlab.com:29484/blog -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword> 
 mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds129484.mlab.com:29484/blog
```

When you start a strapi project, you make this

```
strapi new blog
cd blog
strapi start
```

So you select mondodb how to default db and the cli show the follow questions, and you would be add the following answers, supposing that you have the db data showed before:

- DBname: blog
- host: ds129484.mlab.com
- srv connection: false
- port:    29484
- username: username created on mlab for your db
- password: username password created on mlab for your db
- authentication db: blog (you have put the name of your db)
- enable ssl: false

You press Enter and you project would be run perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must have Node 10 or above. If you still getting error edit the following file:

config/host.json 
Use an higher timeout value.

```
{
```

"timeout": 60000,
......
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on the correct node version, goto the **configuration.js** found in **node_modules/strapi/lib/core/configurations.js** and update lines 331-333.

**Replace**

```
this.config.admin.url = this.config.admin.devMode ?
(new URL(adminPath, `http://${this.config.host}:4000`)).toString():
(new URL(adminPath, url)).toString();
```

**With**

```
this.config.admin.url = this.config.admin.devMode ? `http://${this.config.host}:4000/admin`:`http://${this.config.host}:1337/admin`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:
Just upgrade your node js installation to version 10